# Django filter with distinct and values issue

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
>>> y = Menu.objects.filter(level=1).values('name').distinct()
>>> y
[{'name': u'Desserts'}, {'name': u'Wings'}, {'name': u'Biriyani'}, {'name': u'Starters'}, {'name': u'Desserts'}, {'name': u'Starters'}, {'name': u'Biriyani'}]
```

It is not giving me a distinct result set. How can i achieve distinct values?

According to both the solutions, i got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 138, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 162, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1217, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 794, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("myapp_menu"."name") "myapp_...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [note here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)-- if you are using `order_by` the field you are ordering on will be included in the `DISTINCT`. You don't show an `order_by` in the query but if you have one set in the `Meta` class of your `Menu` model it will still apply.

Comment: oh fantastic... this worked for me: y = Menu.objects.filter(level=1).values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('name').distinct()

Answer (score 2):

Use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) instead of values and set flat parameter in values_list:

```
y = set(Menu.objects.filter(level=1).values_list('name', flat=True))
```

Pass your value list to set function and it create a set with unique values like Joey Wilhelm write in comment.

Comment: this is still not giving me distinct values... i got this: [u'Desserts', u'Wings', u'Biriyani', u'Starters', u'Desserts', u'Starters', u'Biriyani']

Comment: same error i mention to Joey with the distinct('name')

Comment: If you want to use values_list, you would want to do something like:  `y = set(Menu.objects.filter(level=1).values_list('name', flat=True))`. Note, however, that this will not give you a QuerySet, if that is what you are desiring.

Comment: this worked for me: y = Menu.objects.filter(level=1).values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('name').distinct()

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to Dima's solution, if you are using PostgreSQL, you can specify what field to perform the distinct query on, as described in the [.distinct() documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). For example:

```
y = Menu.objects.filter(level=1).distinct('name').values('name')
```

Comment: i ll post the traceback in the question